# class "org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am using jpasskit for ios passes creation and try to sign passes using bouncycastle. I am facing some issue using jpasskit:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

POM details:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.brendamour</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpasskit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9</version>   

       <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

                <exclusion>  
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

                <exclusion>  
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

          </exclusions> 

      </dependency>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when classes belonging to the same package are loaded from different JAR files, I had the same problem and in my case different BouncyCastle's versions where included as dependencies by different libraries I was using.
I see you already have some exclusions in your POM, try to exclude ALL the conflicting/overlapping versions. In your dependency tree look for *bcmail-jdk{version}-{version}.jar*, *bcprov-jdk{version}-{version}.jar* etc... and keep only one version of them.

Comment: I have tried to exclude every jar.Still facing the same issue.Please suggest.

Comment: My jars were still not getting removed from metadata.My issue is resolved now.Thanks again!!.D:\greenlot_45_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sky30Web\WEB-INF\lib

Answer (score 0):

My jars were still not getting removed from metadata.My issue is resolved now.Thanks again!!.D:\greenlot_45_workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Sky30Web\WEB-INF\lib